# Java Sockets for Social media communication

Tags: java, sockets

I had an idea for a social media that, although I won't tell you what the clever feature is, is using java for the server. My initial thoughts on how to do this was to have the client send data through sockets directly to the server, where the server then processes the data, sends back a response if needed, or passes the data on to the users profile. After getting this to work, I was stoked, but now that I think about it, I am not entirely sure if sockets are the best idea for this. Is using sockets safe? Can the data be intercepted and taken.

Onto one other thing, if you think that sockets are safe to use, is it safe to send data back to the client through sockets. If so, how can I validate that the data sent is genuine data and is not just somebody sending a fake string that looks like the real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using bare `Sockets` the network traffic can be observed by anyone, so you'd need to use `SSLSocket` to provide secure communication. There's no need to perform any additional validation by yourself.

Comment: If you use a socket, isnt it basically peer to peer? or do I have it wrong?

Comment: If you have a client connecting to another client (acting as a server) then you could call it peer to peer, if you have a client connecting to a dedicated server, then you could call it client-server.

Comment: @KobeyRafferty between peers there may be other active network components, so a man in the middle attack is still possible

Comment: @mjn What's that supposed to mean? There are active network components between 2 machines at all times (barring a direct ethernet connection from one to another) and SSL/TLS prevents MITM.

Comment: @Kayaman my comment is only correct for unencrypted peer to peer connections (`If you use a socket, isnt it basically peer to peer`)

Answer (score 0):

Not all client computers are directly connected with the Internet. Firewalls may block your TCP socket connections. The clients then will not be able to connect to other computers.

Comment: Basically how this is going to work is client--> Server then <--client2 Client 2 is basically trying to get data from the server. So ports will block this kind of thing?

Comment: @KobeyRafferty yes, firewalls can block it

Comment: This is not a very good answer. Firewalls *can* block ports, of course that's what they were designed for. However if you're using Clever Social Media, you'd open that port for outside communication. Or maybe Clever Social Media server runs on port 80 and there's no problem.

Comment: Is it safe running something on port 80?